# Как поместить кэш и профиль Firefox в ОЗУ?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, ram

Долго гуглил и перепробовал разные инструкции по размещению кэша и профиля на RAM диске. В итоге установил **profile-sync-daemon**, но он только профиль синхронизирует между ОЗУ и жестким диском, а кэш нет. Тогда я решил отключить кэш совсем. В about:config изменил следующие настройки:

```
network.http.use-cache = false
browser.cache.offline.enable = false
browser.cache.disk.enable = false
browser.cache.disk.smart_size.enabled = false
browser.cache.disk_cache_ssl = false
browser.cache.memory.enable = false
```

но это не помогло и Firefox по-прежнему создавал папку ~/.cache/mozilla/ с временными файлами.

Тогда я решил попробовать создать отдельный RAM диск и переместить туда кэш.

```
mkdir ~/RAM-drive-tmpfs
```

И добавил в конец файла /etc/fstab строку:

```
tmpfs   ~/RAM-drive-tmpfs   tmpfs    rw     0     0
```

Все успешно и папка работает, но кэш теперь находится частично в ***~/RAM-drive-tmpfs*** а частично в  ***~/.cache/mozilla/***

Также пробовал параметр ***browser.cache.disk.parent_directory*** в about:config
но ничего не вышло.

Система Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver).

Прошу помощи у специалистов по Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одно время я переносил кэш хрома в память. для этого точно также создал в fstab новую точку монтирования и скопировал туда кэш (/home/user/.cache/chromium/Default). Оригинальный каталог с кэшем переименовал в Default_ 
Затем создал симлик Default -> /mnt/RAM/Default

Перед выключением ПК синхронизировал его скриптом на рабочем столе:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/rsync -av /mnt/RAM/Default/* /home/user/.cache/chromium/Default_/
```

В cron добавил (заливка в память свежего кэша через 10 сек после загрузки):

```
@reboot sleep 10; rsync -a /home/user/.cache/chromium/Default_/* /mnt/RAM/Default/
```

Думаю с Firefox можно поступить также.